# how to set bios to default

Tags: bios, cmos

my laptop is locked up by a BIOS password I mistyped. Now I can´t access windows. All I get is a password prompt. I removed the CMOS battery for over an hour but nothing changed. Tried looking for a BIOS update on the HP website but there is no BIOS installation software for my HP Pavilion Chromebook 14 G1. Tried to look for jumpers on the motherboard but didn't find any. Went to https://bios-pw.org/ to get the recovery password for my laptop which error code is **"i 71723528"** but i can´t fully type the code it gives me which is **"yundefinedx3x7fq7u"** it won't let me type the digits in the code. I'm kind of desperate right now. I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

Contact the manufacturer they should have special software to update the firmware/BIOS and clear bad settings. They absolutely have this and a good helpdesk or service engineer should be able to help you, it won't be free of charge though.

Comment: Yes that seems like the only option I have left.